# Capture number inside tag in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt

My tag struct looks like this:

```
<sml8/>
```

combination of `<` , `sml` , `digits (one or two)` and `/>`
Is there anyway to capture number inside tag?

for example in above I want capture 8 inside

I've defined regular expression and I tried to capture it by digit position but it's not working for me.

```
QRegExp rxlen("<sml(.*)/>");
int index = rxlen.pos(3);
```

I guess it's not correct way and it gives me position of digit although I want value of digit (or digits).

Comment: `QRegExp rxlen("<sml(\\d{1,2})/>");`

Comment: How it's not helps you? whats the output?

Comment: Try `int pos = rxlen.indexIn("<sml8/>"); // QString str = rxlen.capturedTexts()[1]` to access the captured group.

Comment: index value is -1 @Kasramvd

Comment: @stribizhev QString str = rxlen.capturedTexts()[1] is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [capturedTexts()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts) together with `<sml(\\d{1,2})/>` regex (it matches `<sml` literally, then 1 or 2 digits capturing them into Captured group 1, then `/>`:

```
QString str = "<sml8/>";
QRegExp rxlen("<sml(\\d{1,2})/>");
int pos = rxlen.indexIn(str);
QStringList list = rxlen.capturedTexts();
QString my_number = list[1];
```