# Qt - how to define regular expression in QString

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I've [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557088/qt-capture-digit-inside-tag) on regular expression on Qt , I want to replace all sub string with specific regular expression with image.

my tag struct is combination of `<` , `sml` , `digits (one or two)` and `/>` and my QString is `draftMsg`. It will work if I use regular expression once.

for example : "*hello `<sml7/>`*" will be change to hello and photo with label 7 in my directory.

Here is my code:

```
           QRegExp rxlen("<sml(\\d{1,2})/>");
           if (draftMsg.contains(rxlen))
           {
                QString str = rxlen.capturedTexts()[1];
                int index = str.toInt();
                smileyClicked(index-1);

                m_messageEdit->insertHtml(QString("<img src=\":images/smiley/%1_64.png\" width=%2 />")
                                          .arg(index, 2, 10, QLatin1Char('0')).arg(smileyWidth));

                draftMsg = draftMsg.remove(rxlen);
           }
```

Actually it replace wrongly when I write string like : "*hello `<sml7/><sml1/>`*". It will replace both tag to image with label 7.

I searched and I found [it](http://apiexamples.com/cpp/QtCore/QRegExp.html#L3). I trying to use captureCount() to keep Regular expression's number and use it.

I've created this function:

```
void MessageDialog::regInMessage(QString pattern, QString string)
{
    QRegExp regex(pattern);
    if (regex.indexIn(string) < 0) {
        qDebug("Can't find a match.");
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << regex.captureCount();
}
```

But it gives me "1" instead of two.

Any suggestion to count regular expression on my QString?

Comment: what do you get if you print `qDebug() << regex.cap(0);
    qDebug() << regex.cap(1);qDebug() << regex.cap(2);` ??

Comment: I am afraid the question isn't phrased in an understandable way. Could you please reword it?

Comment: I want replace all Regular expression with photo @Zeks

Answer (score 3):

Capture - is a string, that matches an expression within brackets. In your regex `<sml(\\d{1,2})/>` there is only one bracket pair, so the `captureCount` returns 1. In order to process all entrances of regex in a string you need to do something like this (example from Qt's help):

```
 QRegExp rx("(\\d+)");
 QString str = "Offsets: 12 14 99 231 7";
 QStringList list;
 int pos = 0;

 while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
     list << rx.cap(1);
     pos += rx.matchedLength();
 }
 // list: ["12", "14", "99", "231", "7"]
```

Also, if you want to replace a string, a good idea would be to use [QString & QString::replace ( const QRegExp & rx, const QString & after )](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-12).

**UPDATE**

> I'm using QString::replace like this: –  afn
>
> QString draftMsg = query.value(0).toString(); QRegExp
>   rx(""); int pos = 0; QStringList list; while ((pos =
>   rx.indexIn(draftMsg, pos)) != -1) { list << rx.cap(1); pos +=
>   rx.matchedLength(); } for (int k=0 ; k < list.length() ; ++k)
>   draftMsg.replace(QRegExp(""), ""); –  afn
>
> but it doesn't work –  afn

Used your code.

In: `"hello <sml7/><sml1/>"`

Out: `"hello <img src=":images/smiley/7.png" width=%2 /><img src=":images/smiley/1.png" width=%2 />"`

What were you expecting to get?

Also, all this code can be changed to this:

```
QString draftMsg = query.value(0).toString();
draftMsg.replace(QRegExp("<sml(\\d{1,2})/>")
                 , "<img src=\":images/smiley/\\1.png\" width=%2 />");
```

Comment: I'm using QString::replace like this:

Comment: QString draftMsg = query.value(0).toString();
       QRegExp rx("<sml(\\d{1,2})/>");
       int pos = 0;
       QStringList list;

       while ((pos = rx.indexIn(draftMsg, pos)) != -1)
       {
         list << rx.cap(1);
         pos += rx.matchedLength();
       }
       for (int k=0 ; k < list.length() ; ++k)
        draftMsg.replace(QRegExp("<sml"+list[k]+"/>"), "<img src=\":images/smiley/"+list[k]+".png\" width=%2 />");